# Innodb setting in xampp doesn't seem locate my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I created a new mysql database and i want to use foreign keys with it... I googled and found out this...

InnoDB is one of MySQL storage engines, it supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign-keys. However, by default, InnoDB is not enabled by XAMPP. To enable it, locate the my.cnf configuration file (normally in C:/xampp/mysql/bin directory) and search for the following lines:

```
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
```

But the path `C:/xampp/mysql/bin directory` in my system doesn't seem to have such a file...

Look at this image http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/524/mysqln.jpg

Where is my.cnf file?

Any suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just drag `My` icon

[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/7195/mycnf.jpg](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/7195/mycnf.jpg)

to notepad and remove comments from these lines... I have removed comments and posted answer for you...

## Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables

```
skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/"
innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/"
```

### You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %

### of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
```

### Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size

```
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, its `my.ini` but for linux, its `my.cnf`.